# typeOrm migration incremental

Tags: nestjs, migration, typeorm

I use typeOrm for my project on nestjs the problem is that when I create a migration it is not incremental,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w33aV.png)

i'm searching detail on documentation but nothing founded :(,
if I wish to modify my entity in the future it recreates the entire table, instead to make a simple “alter table” request

```
export const dataSourceOption: DataSourceOptions = {
    
        type: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'testnestjs',
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
        migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/*.js'],
        synchronize: true,
      
}
```

Comment: what do you mean migration was not incremental? migration always creates the file name with the suffix using Unix timestamp.

Comment: thank you for your answer in fact the problem is that in my migration file it recreates the create table query several times for example even if I only modify a few fields in my entity

Comment: you shouldn't set  `synchronize: true,` it auto-create a table or column when you change your entity even if you not create your migration file